# Angular-Xeditable e-pattern not accepting valid regular expression

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex, validation, x-editable

I am trying to validate the user input of a text field using e-pattern from the angular-xeditable directive. I have built the regular expression using an online regex builder/tester and it does exactly what I want however angular-xeditable doesn't seem to recognize the expression as being valid. It shows the below even when the expression is valid.

requirements:

- Value must be >= 0.0 or <= 1.0
- Value can have one or two decimal places
- First decimal place can be a digit between 0-9
- Second decimal place should be either 0 or 5

valid entry: 0.5, 0.95, 0.40, 1.0

regex:

```
 ^((0+(\.[0-9][05]?))|1+(\.0))$
```

code:

`<span e-pattern="/^((0+(\.[0-9][05]?))|1+(\.0))$/"  e-required ng-show="!tableform.$visible"   editable-text="user.available" e-form="tableform" onbeforesave="checkAvailable($data)">{{ user.available}} </span>`

message:

[image]

Is there anything I'm missing or need to amend to the expression or span tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fail, I just figured out the issue it's incredibly simple e-pattern does not require /^ or $/ before or after the expression, should instead read:

```
 e-pattern="((0+(\.[0-9][05]?))|1+(\.0))"
```